# Correlate data from two CSVs and write the data to the first CSV using Python

Tags: python, database, csv

I'm having trouble figuring out where to dive in on this personal project and I was hoping this community could help me create a Python script to deal with this data.

I have a CSV file that contains a list of meals fed to dogs at an animal rescue, associated by with the kennel number:

Source CSV - mealsandtreats.csv

```
blank_column,Kennel_Number,Species,Food,Meal_ID
,1,Dog,Meal,11.2
,5,Dog,Meal,45.2
,3,Dog,Meal,21.4
,4,Dog,Meal,17
,2,Dog,Meal,11.2
,4,Dog,Meal,21.4
,6,Dog,Meal,17
,2,Dog,Meal,45.2
```

I have a second CSV file that provides a key which maps the meals to what treats come with the meal:

Meal to Treat Key - MealsToTreatsKey.csv

```
Meals_fed,Treats_fed
10.1,2.4
11.2,2.4
13.5,3
15.6,3.2
17,3.2
20.1,5.1
21.4,5.2
35.7,7.7
45.2,7.9
```

I need to take every meal type (eg; drop duplicate entries) that was delivered from table 1, find the associated treat type, and then create an individual entry for every time a treat was served to a specific kennel. The final result should look something like this:

Result CSV - mealsandtreats.csv

```
blank_column,Kennel_Number,Species,Food,Meal_ID
,1,Dog,Meal,11.2
,5,Dog,Meal,45.2
,3,Dog,Meal,21.4
,4,Dog,Meal,17
,2,Dog,Meal,11.2
,4,Dog,Meal,21.4
,6,Dog,Meal,17
,2,Dog,Meal,45.2
,1,Dog,Treat,2.4
,5,Dog,Treat,7.9
,3,Dog,Treat,5.2
,4,Dog,Treat,3.2
,1,Dog,Treat,2.4
,4,Dog,Treat,5.2
```

Would prefer to do this with the csv module and not Pandas, but I'm open to using Pandas if necessary.

I have a bit of code so far just opening the CSVs, but I'm really stuck on where to go next:

```
import csv

with open('./meals/results/foodToTreats.csv', 'r') as t1, 
open('./results/food.csv', 'r') as t2:
    key = t1.readlines()
    map = t2.readlines()

with open('./results/food.csv', 'w') as outFileF:
        for line in map:
            if line not in key:
                outFileF.write(line)

with open('./results/foodandtreats.csv', 'w') as outFileFT:
        for line in map:
            if line not in key:
                outFileFT.write(line)
```

So basically I just need to take every treat entry in the 2nd sheet, search for matching associated food entries in the 1st sheet, look up the kennel number associated with that entry and then write it to the 1st sheet.

Giving it my best shot in pseudo code, something like:

```
for x in column 0,y: 
    y,1 = Z 

food = x
treat = y
kennel_number = z

when x,z: 
    writerows('', {'kennel_number"}, 'species', '{food/treat}',  
{'meal_id"})
```

Update: Here is the exact code I'm using, thanks to @wwii. Seeing a minor bug:

```
import csv
import collections

treats = {}
with open('mealsToTreatsKey.csv') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        meal,treat = line.strip().split(',')
        treats[meal] = treat

new_items = set()
Treat = collections.namedtuple('Treat', ['blank_column','Kennel_Number','Species','Food','Meal_ID'])

with open('foodandtreats.csv') as f1:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
    for row in reader:
        row['Food'] = 'Treat'
        row['Meal_ID'] = treats[row['Meal_ID']]
        new_items.add(Treat(**row))
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

with open('foodandtreats.csv', 'a') as f1:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f1, fieldnames)
    for row in new_items:
        writer.writerow(row._asdict())
```

This works perfectly except for one small bug. The first new row written isn't starting on its own line: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVaCt.png)

Comment: If is a personal project I strongly suggest you to use `pandas`. It's going to take 2 lines for `read_csv`, 1 line to drop duplicates and 1 `left join`

Comment: @user32185 Okay, awesome, you've convinced me. Any tips on good documentation? :D

Comment: I can help you with a full answer. But please first open the files ( using `df =  pd.read_csv('./meals/results/foodToTreats.csv')`) with pandas and post here the output of `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Which duplicates are you referring to? if Kennel one gets Meal 11.2 three times how many treat entries should there be?

Comment: @wwii If kennel 1 gets Meal 11.2 3 times, I only need one resulting entry associating treat 2.4 with Kennel 1. 

If meal 11.2 was served to kennel 1, 7, and 20, I'd need resulting treat 2.4 entries for kennel 1, 7 and 20.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2823755)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary mapping meals to treats

```
treats = {}
with open(treatfile) as f2:
    for line in f2:
        meal,treat = line.strip().split(',')
        treats[meal] = treat
```

Iterate over the meal file and create set of new entries. Use namedtuples for the new items.

```
import collections
new_items = set()
Treat = collections.namedtuple('Treat', ['blank_column','Kennel_Number','Species','Food','Meal_ID'])

with open(mealfile) as f1:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
    for row in reader:
        row['Food'] = 'Treat'
        row['Meal_ID'] = treats[row['Meal_ID']]
        new_items.add(Treat(**row))
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
```

Open the meal file (again) for appending and write the new entries

```
with open(mealfile, 'a') as f1:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f1, fieldnames)
    for row in new_items:
        writer.writerow(row._asdict())
```

---

If the meals file does not end with a newline character, you will need to add one before writing the new `treat` lines. Since you have control of the files you should just make sure it always ends in a blank line.

Comment: Looks like we're on the right track. When I try to run this code I get the error -   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foodToTreatsMapper.py", line 18, in <module>
    new_items.add(Treat(**row))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank_column'

Comment: When I execute my solution with your example data/files I do not get an error.  It looks like the error is saying that you are trying to make a `Treat` (namedtuple) and you are passing it an invalid keyword.  Did you define the namedtuple as I did in my solution? Did you misspell `blank_column` in that definition?

Comment: Can confirm *"execute with your example data/files I do not get an error"*:

Comment: @wwii I went ahead and updated the original post with the code I'm using. It's almost exactly what you posted. Do you see any mistakes? Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: @wwii Got it to work. There was a problem with my CSV files. There is one last small bug, which I outline above. Otherwise, the script seems to be working great!

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for including the two links as well. Much appreciated on all fronts.

Comment: Ran into an interesting problem when I ran this script against my full data set. Some entries in the foodandtreats.csv don't come with a treat, and so there is no associated entry in the mesalsToTreats.csv key. This causes the script to throw a key error. Is there an easy way to skip the entries that didn't come with a treat?

Comment: @user10028246 if you anticpate `KeyError`s you should [handle them](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) as described in the Tutorial section for handling Exceptions.

Comment: @wwii Your links to answers that teach me things are literally the best thing I could ever ask for. I was able to make the changes I need and get it working perfectly. Thank you so much.